# Inconsistent execution of JavaScript code

Tags: javascript, html

I want to read images that are provided by a user via Drag and Drop, and render thumbnails and output them to the browser.

Here's my code:

```js
function drop(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    var files = event.dataTransfer.files;
    var container = document.getElementById('dragRec');
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(){
        container.innerHTML += '<img width="250" height="250" src="'+ reader.result +'" />';
    }
    var itCount = files.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < itCount; i++)
    {
        reader.readAsDataURL(files[i]);
    }
}
```

When loading images one-by-one, everything is OK.

But when grabbing several images - executing it in normal time will output only one image or (maybe) will create an empty `img` tag with no `src`.

However if I run it step-by-step (using FireBug), everything is loaded, everything is perfect (all images are present).

I'd like to know what is the reason for that.

**Update:**

Chris Perkins and  kamus brought me to the point that asynchronous work of `FileReader` caused clearing the `FileReader.result` variable before the onload handler accessed it which means that the `img` element will have null in `src` attribute.

So I came up with the following solution:

```
function drop(event)
{
    event.preventDefault();
    var files = event.dataTransfer.files;
    var container = document.getElementById('dragRec');
    var readerList = [];
    var itCount = files.length;
    for(var i = 0; i < itCount; i++)
    {
        readerList.push(new FileReader());
        readerList[i].onload = function(){
            container.innerHTML += '<img width="250" height="250" src="'+ this.result +'" />';
        }
        readerList[i].readAsDataURL(files[i]);
        formData.append('file[]', files[i]);
    }
}
```

It is now working but don't really like how it looks. Any recommendations, please?

Comment: It looks like you are re-using FileReader(). You make one instance of it, and use it to asynchronously load several URLs.  I am not familiar with that API, but if I had to guess I'd suggest not reusing it. Make a new instance inside your for loop, assign the onload handler, and then make the call to readAsDataURL.    I did a quick scan of the docs on MDN, and it looks like your usage is not incorrect. But given the behavior you describe, try no resuing.

Comment: You need to create a instance of 'FileReader' for every image , and set your function to a variable to set it more easy

Comment: @ChrisPerkins, kamus:
New instance of object didn't solve the problem but please take a look on the code added to question. Maybe you will have some ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you already noted that its a problem of `async` behaviour of `FileReader`. Here is another option as how you can use `FileReader` for multiple files.

```js
var bucket = document.getElementById('bucket');

var read = function(file) {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  reader.onload = function() {
    bucket.innerHTML += "<img src='" + reader.result + "' width='70'/>";
  };
};

var load = function(e) {
  var files = e.dataTransfer.files;
  var l = files.length;
  var img = false;
  var file;
  while (file = files[--l])
    if (file.type.match(/image\/*/)) {
      img = true;
      read(file);
    }
  if (!img)
    bucket.innerHTML = "No image file found ...";
  return false;
};
```

```css
#bucket {
  position: relative;
  height: 60vh;
  margin: 5px;
  border: 2px dashed grey;
  overflow: auto;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
}
#bucket img {
  border: 1px dotted grey;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<p>Drag-drop image files below ...</p>
<div id="bucket" ondrop="return load(event);" ondragover="return false"></div>
```